# how to implement the Eurion constellation security measure

Tags: security, pdf

This week I learned that there is a hidden pattern on money (banknotes in particular), called the eurion constellation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation

I work for a company that handles electronic documents. And it'd be pretty cool to be able to embed this pattern in such a way that the resulting document can no longer be printed.

I have tried creating a PDF document that contains the constellation, but I must be doing something wrong. I was able to print and scan this PDF perfectly fine.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uejiebty0kh9v7t/eurion.pdf?dl=0

Does anyone have experience with these hidden security features?

Comment: Joris, can you comment on the answer. If you don't expect another answer, I'll award the bounty.

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but this is what I found. I was able to prevent a document from being **photocopied** (Ricoh copier) by adding eurion constellations to it. Most bills use yellow for the circle, so that's what I used (I tried black, and those didn't work). I also assume they need to be a specific size. I was using the same size as on euro bills. I think that's the main reason your test pdf failed. I also think you'd need more than just one constellation. Euro bills have between 4 and 15 constellations. Here is the code I used to generate my test PDF https://output.jsbin.com/nikoxod/26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From both the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation) and the referenced [patent application](https://www.google.com/patents/US5845008), it seems that EURion is intended to prevent *copying*, not printing or scanning; all references refer to color photocopying and photocopying machines. There might be another anti-counterfeiting method that will prevent *printers* from printing banknotes, but it doesn't seem to be EURion.

Comment: Scanning and printing also doesn't work for (PDFs with illustrations of) bank notes. Even importing an image in Photoshop results in an error. The OP's question is: how can we make a PDF document that shows the same behavior?

Comment: From the wikipedia article linked, and [this informative post](http://sec.cs.ucl.ac.uk/users/smurdoch/projects/currency/), whatever Photoshop and other image processing tools use to identify currency, it isn't EURion. I can't find anything on what printers/scanners use to identify currency, but it also isn't EURion, at least not generally. The only guaranteed correct answer to your restatement of the OP's question is "make it a PDF of a banknote".

Comment: FYI: I am waiting for Joris' comments to award the bounty.

Comment: Further testing at iText seems to back up the notion that there is more than just this pattern. I think F. Stephen Q is as close as we're going to get to a full answer. I wholeheartedly support awarding him the bounty.
Thank you for your effort, and thank you Bruno for setting a bounty.

Comment: OK, bounty awarded! Thank you, F. Stephen Q!

Comment: No problem! Sorry that there wasn't a more useful answer out there :/

Comment: This is not the answer. I cannot print a partial scan of a 20 euro bill.
I'd like to be able to prevent copying our own value tokens.